# sbrautaset's JSON-framework Objective-C: Getting null for objectWithString

Tags: objective-c, json

I have some python code for Google App Engine that responds with the string `{"sample_list": [{"message": "Hello, world.", "name": "Human"}]}` I am using [this](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) JSON-framework developed by sbrautaset to convert the string to an object that I can use (NSDictionary in this case). I am following the tutorial [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html) to use the framework.

My problem is that I am getting null for `[jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:NULL]` where jsonString is `{"sample_list": [{"message": "Hello, world.", "name": "Human"}]}` and jsonParser is an instance of `SBJSON` from the framework.

I am guessing that the parser is not recognizing the string as a JSON format. Any insight would be appreciated, as I am completely new to JSON.

Thank you!

**UPDATE: The Server Side Python Code**

```
outer_dict = {}
middle_list = []
inner_dict = {}
inner_dict["name"] = "Human"
inner_dict["message"] = "Hello, world."
middle_list.append(inner_dict)
outer_dict["sample_list"] = middle_list
json_message = simplejson.dumps(outer_dict)
self.response.out.write(json_message)
```

**The Client Side Objective-C Code**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theurl"];
NSString *jsonString = [self stringWithUrl:url];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
id myObj = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSLog(@"%@", myObj);
```

**stringWithUrl**

```
- (NSString *) stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                        timeoutInterval:30];
NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error; 

urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{"sample_list": ["message": "Hello, world.", "name": "Human"]}

You should use a JSON encoder on the server side to encode objects into JSON strings. This way you won't mistakenly produce invalid strings.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using Python's simplejson to encode my objects to JSON strings. I had the inner {}, because I will ultimately have a list of dictionaries. Would this cause a problem?

Comment: Ok, your right to use the inner {} then. Strange... The string appears valid. Catch the error, instead of passing error:NULL pass

NSError *error = nil;
[jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", error);

This may help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I just did what you suggested, and I got Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 "Unrecognised leading character" I am not sure what this is referring to, since the string looks fine.

Comment: When I convert my JSON strings into objects, I use the following: id myObj = [jsonString JSONValue];    Try using that method instead. Log your jsonString too. Make sure the string is what your expecting it to be and not a "server error" message.

Comment: Hmmm. I am still getting "Unrecognised leading character," and I double checked that my string actually says {"sample_list": [{"message": "Hello, world.", "name": "Human"}]}

Comment: I just copied and was able to parse that string. Maybe there is a hidden character? Could you post the code that is encoding (server side) and decoding (client side)?

Comment: Instead of calling the URL to get the string (which looks formatted correctly to me), I explicitly declared NSString *string = @"{\"sample_list\": [{\"message\": \"Hello, world.\", \"name\": \"Human\"}]}"; id myObj = [string JSONValue]; NSLog(@"%@", myObj);
And that works for some reason... I don't see how the two strings are any different :/

Comment: Oh haha, I just did what you did without knowing.

Comment: This is the Python code I have in GET that encodes the object

outer_dict = {}
  middle_list = []
  inner_dict = {}
  inner_dict["name"] = "Human"
  inner_dict["message"] = "Hello, world."
  middle_list.append(inner_dict)
  outer_dict["sample_list"] = middle_list
  json_message = simplejson.dumps(outer_dict)
  self.response.out.write(json_message)

Comment: I updated the question statement since the code is hard to read in the comments. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you post the method [self stringWithUrl:url];

Comment: Alright, i've gone as far as to replicate your code in an app with a server. It works. Other than the method stringWithUrl, everything else seems ok. I bet your encoding is wrong. Are you using NSUTF8StringEncoding?

Comment: Yup, that is the encoding that I am using.

Comment: I used that method and it worked too!!! Arg. Strange. Try fetching the data from the server with this line NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; On a side note, there are a couple issues with that method. When passing variables by reference (&response), be sure these references are pointing to nil. NSURLResponse *response = nil; NSError *error = nil; And your returning string is leaked. You want return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

Comment: Really!! Wow. Let me know if you find the source of the line break.

Comment: Wow, I just got rid of all of my print statements from the GET method. I had no idea that they could affect the response. Thanks for your help!!!